# Javascript timeline with relative dates and times

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use Simile timeline to show a science sequence, but I'd like it to show events from t=0  to t=100000 seconds (I don't care about dates).  I've tried futzing around with assigning arbitrary dates, but I'm having serious issues defining 100 second/interval units.  Does anyone have suggestions on an alternative javascript timeline that can do this? Or does anyone have recommendations on hacking simile to make this work?

Comment: Your question is pretty vague, are you trying run a function at 100 secnod intervals, or just establish a timeline of 100 second increments from some datee/time?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the interval in milliseconds (ms) between two date objects simply by subtracting them:

```
var a = new Date('2011/05/05 12:00:00');
var b = new Date('2011/05/06 12:00:00');
alert(a + '\n' + b + 
  '\n\nDifference in ms: ' + (b - a)); // 86400000
```

If you want to increment a date object by 100 seconds, then you can use get/setSeconds:

```
a.setSeconds(a.getSeconds() + 100);
alert(a + '\n' + b + 
  '\n\nDifference in ms: ' + (b - a)); // 86300000
```

Answer (score -1):

have you try with setTimeOut???

**sample**

```
var t=setTimeout(function(){
  alert("Finish!")
},100000);
```

In the sample, shows a alert at 100 seconds, if you need smaller times you could write it into a for or while...

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.